# Solace LDAP Groups

Tags: solace, solace-mq

Is there a limit on number of LDAP groups that can be added to a solace LDAP profile. We are not able to add more than 100 groups as of now.

Request SEMP:

```
<rpc xmlns="http://www.solacesystems.com/semp/topic_routing/d36m1">
<authentication>
<user-class>
<cli/>
<access-level>
<ldap>
<create>
<group>
<group-name>CN=test_himanshu,OU=SecurityGroups,OU=Process,DC=das,DC=test,DC=com</group-name>
</group>
</create>
</ldap>
</access-level>
</user-class>
</authentication>
</rpc>
```

Response SEMP:

```
<rpc-reply semp-version="soltr/7_2_1">
<!-- ERROR: Failed to create LDAP Group 'CN=test_himanshu,OU=SecurityGroups,OU=Process,DC=das,DC=test,DC=com': max num exceeded.
 -->
<execute-result code="fail" reason="max num exceeded" reasonCode="135"/>
</rpc-reply>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a system limit of 100 LDAP groups for Solace user authentication.

Comment: Is there any way that limit can be changed to support say 2000 groups. We are providing read only access to the users based on LDAP groups

Comment: The limit cannot be changed in the current version of SolOS (7.2.2). There are plans to extend this limit in future releases.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of SolOs 8.13 supports 500 LDAP groups for 3230 and 3560 appliances and up to 5000 LDAP groups with 3560s and the higher end 10GbE NABs and an ADB4.